# If H,K are two Sylow p subgroups of a group G, then can we say something about the existence of the subgroup HK?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Actually I am finding a method, where I can show HK=KH if H,K are two Sylow p subgeoups of a group G.
Please help me to prove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact if we have two different Sylow $p$-subgroups $H,K$ we can never have $HK$ being a subgroup. This follows from the fact that if $HK$ then the order of it is $\frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$, but then as the subgroups are distinct we have that the $|HK|$ has a higher power of $p$ dividing it than $|G$|, which is impossible. 
So we obtain a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $G=S_3$ and $$H=\{e,(1,2)\}, K=\{e,(1,3)\}$$ sylow $2$-subgroups. so $HK$ has order 4, thus not a subgroup of $G$.