# Let $H,K \leq G$ s.t $H,K$ two different Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. Prove $HK$ isn't a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

First of all I wish to explain why I'm opening a new thread:

1. I want to know if my proof is correct.
2. The only proof I could find relies on the assumption $H,K$ are distinct which isn't always the case:

[If H,K are two Sylow p subgroups of a group G, then can we say something about the existence of the subgroup HK?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578466/if-h-k-are-two-sylow-p-subgroups-of-a-group-g-then-can-we-say-something-about-t)

**EDIT**

I was mistaken and the other post solves this question without any other assumption. I will still leave it for others to learn.

---

**Question:**

Let $H,K \leq G$ s.t $H,K$ two different Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. Prove $HK$ isn't a subgroup of $G$.

---

**So this is my proof:**

Assume with contradiction $HK \leq G$. Denote:

$HK \leq G \iff HK=KH \iff (\forall h \in H, \forall k \in K):$

$hk=kh \iff hkh^{-1} = k \iff  hkh^{-1} \in K \iff K \lhd H$

We know $|G| = p^rm$ for some $r \in \mathbb{N}$ and $|H|=|K| =p^r$.

This implies for reasons of size and containment that $H=K$ which derives contradiction to the datum.

**EDIT**

I'm giving this another try:

Since $|H|=|K| = p^r$ and we know $H \neq K$ then $H \cap K \leq HK$ satisfies $|H \cap K| \leq p^{r-1}$.

This implies we have $p$ unique elements in $H \setminus K$ and $p$ unique elements in $K \setminus H$.

Let $k \in K \setminus H$ and $h \in H \setminus K$.

$kh \in KH \iff (kh)^{-1} \in KH \iff h^{-1}k^{-1} \in KH$

$\iff h^{-1} \in K$ and $k^{-1} \in H \iff k \in H$ and $h \in K$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: No, it is not correct that $HK=KH$ implies $\forall h \in H, \forall k \in K : hk = kh$.

Comment: $HK=KH$ does not imply that $hk=kh$ for all $k,h$; it implies that for all $h,k$ there exist $h_1,k_1$ such that $hk=k_1h_1$.  And the later implication that $K$ is a normal subgroup of $H$ is wrong, this can only be concluded from the previous line if $K$ is already a subgroup.

Comment: Also, what do you mean about the assumption that $H, K$ are distinct? Obviously if $H = K$ then $HK = H$ is a subgroup, so it is obviously essential to use that hypothesis.

Comment: $HK=KH \iff \forall h \in H, k \in K \,\,\exists k' \in K , h' \in H \, \text{such that} \,\, hk=k'h'$

Comment: @SeanEberhard $H \cap K$ isn't necessarily trivial to the best of my knowledge. Only if $r=1$.

Comment: Who said anything about $H \cap K$?

Comment: @SeanEberhard the other proof I found on the blog uses this assumption to derive contradiction to the size of $HK$. Maybe distinct isn't the correct word in english i should've used.

Comment: @SeanEberhard can I assume $HK=KH \implies N_G(K) = H$ in regards to the action of $G$ on itself by conjugation? if so, would that lead me anywhere?

Comment: I see. I changed distinct to trivial intersection since that seems to be what you intend. Please link to the other question in which the hypothesis $H \cap K = 1$ is used.

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof in the linked question does *not* use the hypothesis $H \cap K = 1$. It just uses the fact that the cardinality of the set $HK$ is $|H||K| / |H\cap K|$. Since $H \cap K$ is a proper subgroup of $K$, $|K|/|H\cap K|$ is an integer divisible by $p$, so $|HK|$ is divisible by a higher power of $p$ than $|G|$, so $|HK|$ does not divide $|G|$. In particular $HK$ cannot be a subgroup.

*Proof that $|HK| = |H||K|/|H\cap K|$:* Consider the map $f:H\times K \to HK$ defined by $(h,k) \mapsto hk$. It is surjective by definition. Consider a point $h_0k_0 \in HK$. The number of preimages is the number of solutions to $hk = h_0k_0$, or $h_0^{-1} h = k_0 k^{-1}$, and the number of solutions is clearly $|H \cap K|$. Therefore the map $f$ is precisely $|H\cap K|$-to-$1$.

*Alternative:* Consider the action of $H$ on $\Omega = G/K$ by left-translation. The stabilizer of $K \in G/K$ is $H \cap K$. The orbit of $K$ consists of the cosets $hK$ with $h \in H$, so the orbit has size $|HK|/|K|$. Therefore by the orbit--stabilizer theorem $|H : H \cap K| =|HK|/|K|$.

Comment: thank you i now understand my mistake. Do you believe my second approach also works?

Comment: @MathStudent101 No, it does not. $h^{-1}k^{-1} \in KH$ does not imply $h^{-1} \in K$ and $k^{-1} \in H$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|G|=p^a n,$
where $p$ does not divide $n$

Then the orders of the Sylow $p$
-subgroups $H,K$
are $p^a.$

Since the intersection $H \cap K$
is a subgroup of $H$
, the order of $H \cap K$
is $p^b$
for some integer $ b \leq a$
by Lagrange’s theorem.
As $H$
and $K$
are distinct subgroups, we must have $b<a.$

Then the number of elements of the product $HK$
is
$$|HK|=\dfrac{|H||K|}{|H∩K|}=p^{2a−b}.$$

Since $b<a$
, we have $2a−b>a$
.

It follows that the product $HK$
cannot be a subgroup of $G$
since otherwise the order $|HK|=p^{2a−b}$
divides $|G|$
by Lagrange’s theorem but $p^a$
is the highest power of $p$
that divides $|G|.$